# How to change perl win32::GUI window title bar image?

Tags: perl

While developing desktop applications using Perl Win32::GUI module in windows OS, a "camel" image is present in the title bar (left most image on window).
Is it possible to change that one? 
If yes, 
what kind of image will support(.gif,.png,.jpg,.ico) for this? and 
which property I need to change/add in the design window that I have written below?

```
  use strict;
  use Win32::GUI;

  my $main = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name    => "Main",
    -title   => "Win32-GUI:Test",
    -left    => 100,
    -top     => 100,
    -width   => 600,
    -height  => 400,
  );

  sub Main_Terminate() {
    print "Main window terminated\n";
    return -1;
  }


  $main->Show();

 Win32::GUI::Dialog();
```

Note: I am developing the application in windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use [SetIcon](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=reference-methods#seticon) method of the main window.

```
$main->SetIcon($icon);
```

where `$icon` have to be instance of either [Win32::Icon](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=icon), [Win32::Bitmap](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=bitmap) or [Win32::BitmapInline](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=bitmapinline).